# Need Help Combining paritions for root filesystem and /host

Tags: partitioning

I am hoping somebody can help me combine the partitions that are mounted at / and /host.  I am running Ubuntu 15.04.  I am out of space on the root filesystem and think it would be easiest if they were combined.  I would like to follow the instructions at [askubuntu.com/questions/117014/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-merge-and-home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117014/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-merge-and-home), but am having some trouble.  If I run `df -h`, I get:

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             24G     0   24G   0% /dev
tmpfs           4.8G  9.5M  4.7G   1% /run
/dev/sdb5       215G   30G  186G  14% /host
/dev/loop0       29G   27G  645M  98% /
tmpfs            24G   28M   24G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            24G     0   24G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb2        96M   24M   73M  25% /boot/efi
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           4.8G   60K  4.8G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1       7.6G  1.1G  6.5G  15% /media/thomas/UBUNTU 15_0
/dev/sr0        7.4G  7.4G     0 100% /media/thomas/MatLabR2016aWin`

As you can see, the /dev/loop0 partition is 98% full.  I would like to combine it with the /dev/sdb5 partition.  Actually, I think that the former is already part of the latter, but the root filesystem doesn't have access to it for some reason.  When I boot to a live Ubuntu disk and run GParted, I get this:

[GParted window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqSAJ.jpg)

I guess the /dev/loop0 partition where the root filesystem is isn't really it's own partition?  Anyway, I'm not able to resize it in GParted, but want to be able to make use of all of the space on /dev/sdb5.

I think their are some technical inaccuracies here, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do.  Can anybody help me with this?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you use Wubi to install Ubuntu? For virtual Wubi partitions you can follow  [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk). My favorite solution is "Live Resize" at the bottom of the site. But you should install a newer Ubuntu version. 15.04 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I installed using a live Ubuntu USB on a UEFI system. Unfortunately I am not able to upgrade Ubuntu as I am using CUDA 7.5 which does not support newer versions.

Comment: Your configuration looks like my Ubuntu 16.04 installed by Wubi.  As some experts explained me, Ubuntu has full access to your Windows drive which is mounted as /host. But system files need a Linux file system. Therefore a large file within Windows drive contains a Linux file system mounted as / . If you need more space for the Linux file system you can expand the large file. The name of the large file is /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk within Ubuntu. If you want real partitions with a Linux file system, you can [MigrateWubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi).If you really used Wubi.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I realized that I did in fact use Wubi to install, and so am trying to use the script at the link you gave, but am having a problem.  Right now, when I run `sudo bash wubi-move.sh /dev/sdb6 /dev/sdb7`, after the source validates, I get:
`wubi-move.sh:  Validating migration target(s)...
wubi-move.sh:  partition /dev/sdb6 must be type 83 - Linux.
wubi-move.sh:  partition /dev/sdb7 must be type 82 - Linux swap.
wubi-move.sh:  Validation of target(s) failed`

Running `fdisk -l` lists /dev/sdb6 as "Linux filesystem" and /dev/sdb7 as "Linux swap".

Any ideas?

Comment: If an error occurs you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/bcbc/Wubi-move/issues) or you can [migrate Wubi manually](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubiManually). Last time, I used the migration script with 14.04 and UEFI. It worked without problems.