# Repartition to increase /home size

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to increase the size of /home because its running out of space.  `/home` is at the end and its inside `/dev/sda4` and there is no unallocated space available.

Kindly take a look at the below gparted screenshot.

[image]

Comment: oh so it cant be done using gparted :(

Comment: I think you can if you want to keep the separate `/home`. I just offered an alternative.

Comment: Is keeping a separate `/home` not recommended? And how can I increase the `/home` size without merging to `/`?

Comment: Yes, you could shrink `/dev/sda3` to make room for a bigger `/dev/sda5` but that would be a lengthier process than what @Melebius suggests.

Comment: The procedure using `gparted` would be: shrink sda3, move sda4 to the left, move sda5 to the left, and resize (grow) sda5. Start by making a backup of everything that you care about.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the solution and alternative. Kindly post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I would recommend keeping a separate `/home` when your `/` (and eventually other partitions) is at a stable size, i.e. you're not installing many applications, but maybe working with a lot of data. For your next system, you may want to consider using [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29), but I'm not sure it works well when sharing a system with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have enough space in the root (`/`) partition, I would merge `/home` into `/`. Then optionally delete the extended partition completely and extend the combined root partition to utilize the free space. This operation will be most likely faster than resizing a partition at the end of the disk.

Before you proceed, I recommend making a backup, preferably the complete disk using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Then follow these instructions (from an [answer by htorque](https://askubuntu.com/a/117021/250300)):

> - Boot the live CD/USB.
> - Mount the root partition to `/mnt/root`.
> - Mount the home partition to `/mnt/oldhome`.
> - Copy the data using `rsync`:
>
>   ```
>   sudo rsync -avz --hard-links --numeric-ids /mnt/oldhome/ /mnt/root/home
>   ```
> - Open `/mnt/root/etc/fstab` and delete the entry for your home partition.
> - Unmount the root and home partition and reboot the system. If everything works as expected you can reboot again into the live system and then:
> - Open GParted.
> - Delete the old home partition, resize the root partition.

---

> Is keeping a separate /home not recommended?

It’s just a matter of taste. Having all data in one partition avoids the problem of having one full partition and another almost empty, like in your case. On the other hand, a separate `/home` partition is good for backup and reinstallation.

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion (using `gparted`):

1. Make a backup of any important data on the disk.
2. Shrink `/dev/sda3` by, let's say, 50 Gb. You have more than that free, so the exact number is not important.
3. Move the left boundary of `/dev/sda4` to the left by the same amount.
4. Move the left boundary of `/dev/sda5` to the left (as `/dev/sda4` is an extended partition, moving its boundaries does not move the "inner" partitions)
5. Grow (= resize to enlarge) `/dev/sda5` to the desired size.

Actually, it may be possible to do the last two steps in one go. I am not sure about that.

This will require physically moving large numbers of blocks, so it will be a lengthy process.

Comment: I believe that this answer doesn't put enough **emphasys** in backing up. That's the 0th rule before doing anything like this.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It's the first action on *my* list.

Comment: Before taking any action, you should already have a backup.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't follow your comment. My first step is to make a backup. How do you suggest I should improve my answer?

Comment: More emphasys on the backup. The list, as it is, kinda implies that the backups are part of  `gparted`, when they should be before you even consider using gparted. I would move it to be the first line, outside the list. What do you think?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel go ahead and write a better answer. I don't see where I suggest that backups are a part of `gparted`.

Comment: I can't write a better answer. Just believe that the backup line should be the first line. Currently, you first line is `My suggestion (using gparted):`.