# Merged /home partition into root partition: problems

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, fsck, merge

In Ubuntu 20.04, I had separate / (root) and /home partitions. I wanted to replace the /home partition with a home folder. There are many articles and suggestions on how to do this. Possibly I chose the wrong one; possibly I misunderstood it.

I used `mv` to move the contents of /home to the home folder. This seems to have been an inferior approach, compared to what now seems to be [the best advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/117021/80644). I am seeing various malfunctions. For example, icons can't be added or removed from the dock, and Nautilus freezes the entire system after a series of indications that it is unable to find /home/[user]. But the system passes `fsck`.

My question: is there a simple fix, or a set of simple fixes, or is this rather likely to be a quagmire?

Comment: It may help if you're specific as to what you did. I'd believe a *fix* would be possible, but you've not actually said what you did, only that you followed an *unspecified* guide that isn't helpful.  I'd assume everything was done from *live* media so I'd not expect issues unless you forgot something; where by I'd reboot/return to *live* media & correct whatever you forgot.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Unfortunately, I don't have the link to the source I followed, and as I say I may have misunderstood it in any event. What I did was just to use *mv* rather than what appears to be the more commonly suggested *rsync* with various options. In the linked example, those options are -avz --hard-links --numeric-ids. I don't know how/whether those options achieve something that a simple *move* would not achieve.